# OCR like Auto Cheat application

Tags: iphone, ocr

I am intending to write a simple OCR engine for iPhone like "Auto Cheat" application which scans game board of "words with friends". How should I go about doing it? Are there any source codes available for me to use and alter it according to my need? I am a newbie to this OCR thingy. Pls help.

Thanks

Comment: What research have you done? Don't expect people to just give you source code.

Comment: As posed, this is way too broad a question to be answered here. You're going to need to focus on one aspect of this (image processing, OCR, the processing of the game board, etc.) and ask specific questions about how to do that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check out [OpenCV for iPhone](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/documentation/tutorial/). This question: [Tutorial for iPhone OpenCV on shape recognising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738792/tutorial-for-iphone-opencv-on-shape-recognising), has some links that will help you out.  Keep in mind if you have never worked with OpenCV before this is not a easy project to start with.  Good Luck!